# Does a proxy contract need to declare state variables?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, delegatecall, proxy-contracts

There is no variable declaration in the proxy contract. Does the returned data from the delegate call auto-generate the variables for the proxy contract?

```
contract Logic {

    uint256 varA;
    uint256 varB;
    string varC;

    function initialise(unit _varA, uint256 _varB, string memory _varC) external initializer {
      varA = _varA;
      varB = _varB;
      varC = _varC;
   }

}


contract Proxy {
    // address of logic contract
    address public immutable logic;

    // ======== Constructor =========

    constructor(
        address _logic,
        bytes memory _initializationCalldata
    ) {
        logic = _logic;

        // Delegatecall into the logic contract, supplying initialization calldata
        (bool _ok, bytes memory returnData) =
            _logic.delegatecall(_initializationCalldata);

        // Revert if delegatecall to implementation reverts
        require(_ok, string(returnData));
    }

    // ======== Fallback =========

    fallback() external payable {
        address _impl = logic;
        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize())
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), _impl, ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            let size := returndatasize()
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            switch result
                case 0 {
                    revert(ptr, size)
                }
                default {
                    return(ptr, size)
                }
        }
    }

    // ======== Receive =========

    receive() external payable {} // solhint-disable-line no-empty-blocks
}
```

Comment: Read OpenZeppelin's documentation on [Upgrading smart contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts).

Comment: Side note: [you don't have to use low-level assembly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37601/using-a-high-level-delegate-call-in-upgradable-contracts-since-byzantium) to perform a DELEGATECALL anymore. Here's a [modern implementation](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-proxy/blob/11b9a69850f2e26ee80f8b3686e62f6eb60d44d5/contracts/PRBProxy.sol#L64-L102).